# How to create Kubernetes objects with Status fields?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client, kubernetes-operator, kubernetes-custom-resources

I am using the kubernetes operator to create a custom resource in the cluster, the CR has the `Status` field populated, but when the object gets created the `Status` field is empty.

This is how I am creating the CR:

```
reconcile.Create(ctx, &object)
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish with k8s operator:

[image]

Comment: It's the controller that should write to the Status-part. The client that creates the resource should only write the _desired state_ (spec).

Comment: The controller itself can create objects internally based on the sequence of actions it can take.

Comment: yes, but it is in the reconciliation-loop the controller writes the status for the resources that it reconciles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The architecture of Kubernetes API and resources follows a pattern.

1. Clients may create resources, by specifying a *desired state* (This is the `spec:` part of a resource). This is a "create" request sent to the API Server.
2. Controllers, subscribe/watch to changes of resources, while doing actions in a *reconciliation loop*, they might update the Status of the resource (this is the `status:` part of the resource).

For an example of how a controller is implemented and updates the status, see the [Kubebuilder book: Implementing a Controller - Update the Status](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/controller-implementation.html#2-list-all-active-jobs-and-update-the-status).

The client in the example is a "controller runtime client":

```
"sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client"
```

Example code, where the *reconciler* updates the `status` sub-resource:

```
if err := r.Status().Update(ctx, &cronJob); err != nil {
    log.Error(err, "unable to update CronJob status")
    return ctrl.Result{}, err
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonas, for adding the details, I recognize the k8s operator pattern, I have updated my question with the architecture I am trying to achieve with the operator pattern, when I am syncing (creating) the k8s objects between the k8s clusters, as the status field is not populated in the other cluster that is creating issues.

Comment: in my architecture, I am `creating` the k8s object in another cluster, and that is triggering an event for the operator (which is expected), but as the status field is not there I am unable to judge if the k8s object is coming from another cluster.

Comment: The status of an object can be updated in the `"current"` reconcile loop and not outside (Jonas your explanation says the same thing, thanks).